# dataLabels are not showed in boost mode for line chart

Tags: highcharts

This looks like a bug but maybe I missed something.

This is the chart in normal mode
[image]

And this is with boost on
[image]

Here is the sample on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-evypdv

Change 100 to 1 in line 585 `"boostThreshold": 100,` to turn boost mode on

Any ideas what is wrong?

Link to highcharts documentation on boost: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/boost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the highcharts team this is by design.

Data labels are not supported in boost mode, see: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8612

[image]

Comment: Looks strange for me, but at least the situation is clear now. Thank you. Why not to leave the decision for the customer? I can have 4k points in chart but 10 labels that will not reduce the speed... Never could understand "smart" libraries...